# special character in UNIX

Tags: unix, character

I want to add backspace character literally in my file named junk. So I did following
$ ed
a
my name is happy\b  (here b means I typed backspace so \ gets disapperaed and cursor sits sfter y)
.
w junk
q

But when I do
$ od -cb junk
it doesn't show backspace.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hit `Ctrl+V` before hitting `backspace`.  That tells the shell to treat the following keystroke literally, rather than interpreting its meaning.

Depending on how your terminal is set up, the `backspace` key might be interpreted as `delete`, so you might need to hit `Ctrl+H` instead of `backspace` to get a `backspace` character in your file.

Comment: It doesn't work. When I hit ctrl-V, it shows an underscore and then
pressing backspace deletes that underscore and / remains as it is.
By the way, I am using cygwin software. Does that create problem?

Answer (score 2):

Type ctrl-v, ctrl-h.

ctrl-v says 'insert the next control character literally'. The cursor should change to a highlighted caret.

ctrl-h is the backspace character. It looks like in ed, typing ctrl-h without ctrl-v also inserts a literal backspace, but in other contexts, crtl-h may have some other meaning, and you will need to press ctrl-v first.

EDIT: With the above steps, od -cb gave me:

```
$ od -cb file
0000000   h   e   l   l   o  \b  \n
        150 145 154 154 157 010 012
0000007
```

which looks correct.

When I tried it again with ctrl-v, Backspace (as opposed to ctrl-h), it instead gave

```
$ od -cb file
0000000   h   e   l   l   o 177  \n
        150 145 154 154 157 177 012
0000007
```

177 is the ascii octal code for DEL, not Backspace. This may vary by system, though.